# How do I write chemical reaction-diffusion formula in LaTex?

Tags: chemistry, chemformula

How can I write the following chemical reaction-diffusion formula (see figure) in LaTex?

My main objective is, how do I produce the two way arrows with single letters above and below?

[image]

Comment: Or package `mathtools` with `A \xleftrightharpoons[k_{-1}]{k_{1}} G ` for instance

Comment: The comment from clemens worked!

Comment: I used: `\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}` in TeXstudio & ---->  `$$\ce{A <=>[{k_1}][{k_{-1}}] G}\\$$`

Comment: You should not use `$$`, but otherwise it's perfectly fine to self-answer a question if you found a solution for yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are two suggestions, the first using `chemformula` (via `chemmacros`), the second using `mhchem`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemmacros}
\usepackage{textalpha}
\begin{document}

\begin{subequations}
\begin{equation}
  \ch{A <=>[ $k_1$ ][ $k_{-1}$ ] K}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
  \ch{G <=>[ $k_2$ ][ $k_{-2}$ ] X}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
  \ch{B + X <=>[ $k_3$ ][ $k_{-3}$ ] Y + Z}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
  \ch{2 X + Y <=>[ $k_4$ ][ $k_{-4}$ ] 3 X}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
  \ch{X <=>[ $k_1$ ][ $k_{-1}$ ] \chemOmega}
\end{equation}
\end{subequations}

\end{document}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\begin{document}

\begin{subequations}
\begin{equation}
  \ce{A <=>[$k_1$][$k_{-1}$] K}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
  \ce{G <=>[$k_2$][$k_{-2}$] X}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
  \ce{B + X <=>[$k_3$][$k_{-3}$] Y + Z}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
  \ce{2X + Y <=>[$k_4$][$k_{-4}$] 3X}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
  \ce{X <=>[$k_1$][$k_{-1}$] \Omega}
\end{equation}
\end{subequations}

\end{document}
```

[image]